# Wordpress Theme doesn't output my content from the Backend

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the WordPress theme "ShopIsle" and I can't seem to get it to output text from the back end correctly. I want to add content to the back end and have it appear on the front end but it is not outputting it?

[image: WordPress BE -> FE]

The customizer only offers me options like Product Carousel or Video Banner, but not just a simple text output from the backend.

Anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a choice made by the theme, although it seems odd they didn't hide the WYSIWYG editor in the back end if they weren't going to show the content on the page. Are you interested in editing the theme (or creating a child theme) to try and fix this yourself? If so we can help you here. If you'd rather get help from the theme authors understanding this and changing it then you should probably contact them directly.

Comment: i'd like to fix it in the front-page.php. is there any sort of code which outputs the values of the entry in the BE? im playing around right now with `the_content();`which seems to output exactly that-

Comment: Yes, sounds right to me! (but it's been a while since I did that) If you're editing front-page.php in place then beware of losing your changes if you ever do a theme update, but as long as you're careful (and take backups) it should all be fine.